# Check if Column List Contains Header via Regex - Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to determine if a column has a header or not via VBA. Basically the column will have data following an unknown but identical regex pattern. My plan is to test if `A2` has the same type regex string as `A1`. It would likely even be the same ID + 1. Eg

`A1 = X001`

`A2 = X002`

`Func IsHeader("A") = True`

`A1 = ID's`

`A2 = X001`

`Func IsHeader("A") = False`

I've got an idea to utilize an existing script I made to generate a regex pattern based on an input alphanumerical string, but I'm interested to see what other idea's/ways people might have of solving the issue. I realize there isn't much code, but I know I can do this and I'm working on it now. If you're not interested in answering, thats ok!

Update: Posted Answer, but I'm looking for more than a code review as I realize there is an exchange for that. I'd like to know better ways to achieve goal with a different attack vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got! I'm not sure how SO feels about code reviews, but im interested in what ppl think and how else they could "skin the cat" so please feel free to post an answer.

```
Sub Test()

If IsHeader = True Then
 MsgBox "Has Header"
Else
 MsgBox "No Header"
End If

End Sub

Public Function IsHeader() As Boolean

 A1Pattern = RegExPattern(Range("A1").Value)
 A2Pattern = RegExPattern(Range("A2").Value)

If A1Pattern = A2Pattern Then
 IsHeader = True
End If

End Function


Public Function RegExPattern(my_string) As String
RegExPattern = ""
'''Special Character Section'''
Dim special_charArr() As String
Dim special_char As String

special_char = "!,@,#,$,%,^,&,*,+,/,\,;,:"
special_charArr() = Split(special_char, ",")
'''Special Character Section'''

'''Alpha Section'''
Dim regexp As Object
Set regexp = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

Dim strPattern As String
strPattern = "([a-z])"

With regexp
    .ignoreCase = True
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With
'''Alpha Section'''

Dim buff() As String
'my_string = "test1*1#"
ReDim buff(Len(my_string) - 1)
Dim i As Variant
For i = 1 To Len(my_string)
    buff(i - 1) = Mid$(my_string, i, 1)
    char = buff(i - 1)
    If IsNumeric(char) = True Then
        'MsgBox char & " = Number"
        RegExPattern = RegExPattern & "([0-9])"
    End If
    For Each Key In special_charArr
     special = InStr(char, Key)
      If special = 1 Then
        If Key <> "*" Then
            'MsgBox char & " = Special NOT *"
            RegExPattern = RegExPattern & "^[!@#$%^&()].*$"
        Else
            'MsgBox char & " = *"
            RegExPattern = RegExPattern & "."
        End If
      End If
    Next
    If regexp.Test(char) Then
        'MsgBox char & " = Alpha"
        RegExPattern = RegExPattern & "([a-z])"
    End If
Next
'RegExPattern = Chr(34) & RegExPattern & Chr(34)
'MsgBox RegExPattern
End Function
```